# In Windows 7, where does the "Cascade" function get its resizing dimensions?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Regarding Windows 7's "Cascade" function (when shift-right-clicking a group of windows on the taskbar), this function resizes *every* single window of the group, which I never want, and can't understand why anyone would. Not only that, but it also resizes every window to an absurd width, spanning nearly the entire screen.

Does anyone know where the default resizing-dimensions for this function is stored? I'd guess it's somewhere in the registry, unless it's hardcoded somewhere, like Explorer.

I'd prefer the function do no resizing whatsoever, but short of that, I'd prefer it at least resize to something less absurd.

Comment: Can confirm cascade has traveled all the way up to Windows 10, and can confirm it's _uselessness_ has traveled with it.

Comment: Your username sums up my feelings on this.